# EclipseLink: column name 'version' leads to ORA-00942

Tags: java, oracle11g, eclipselink

Eclipse Link creates a query out of the persistence class in our RCP application like this:

```
select column1, column2, ..., version from table_name
```

Using such a select, we got the error 'ORA-00942', saying table or view does not exists. We are using an Oracle 11g database. The same statement works with a JDBC connection (not using Eclipse Link) without problems. Also within SQLPlus, the statement works. We checked access rights, ensured having the same user, database, and so on with all our tests.
Than we tried to set the annotation of the column version in the persistence class to use double quotes:

```
@Column(name="\"VERSION\"", nullable=false, precision=22)
private BigDecimal version;
```

Afterwards it worked. All the other columns, also the tablename, are not having quotes. Just this column 'version' needs quotes, why ever. The column 'version' was part of a DDL script, which has not used any double quotes. All column names were in upper case. Same for the table name.

In SQLDeveloper, 'version' is marked as keyword. But I can't find any explanation how using the word 'version' as column name could have an effect on a SQL statement.

Does someone know if the keyword 'version' might have an effect on a query within Eclipse Link or Oracle?

Comment: Set EclipseLink logging to finest to have it log the SQL it issues over JDBC to see the difference.  You would have to show the statement you use to create the table in the DDL script to see what might be going wrong, but if name="\"VERSION\"" works, it means case sensitivity is at play somehow when the field was created.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Oracle:

```
select * from V$RESERVED_WORDS where keyword = 'VERSION';


KEYWORD                  LENGTH RESERVED RES_TYPE RES_ATTR RES_SEMI DUPLICATE
-------------------- ---------- -------- -------- -------- -------- ---------
VERSION                       7 N        N        N        N        N
```

this query checks if the 'VERSION' is a keyword (you may need some special privileges to select from this view)

Here is a description of this view:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2048.htm#REFRN30204

```
Column      Datatype        Description

KEYWORD     VARCHAR2(30)    Name of the keyword
LENGTH      NUMBER          Length of the keyword
RESERVED    VARCHAR2(1)     A value of Y means that the keyword cannot be used as an identifier. A value of N means that it is not reserved.
RES_TYPE    VARCHAR2(1)     A value of Y means that the keyword cannot be used as a type name. A value of N means that it is not reserved.
RES_ATTR    VARCHAR2(1)     A value of Y means that the keyword cannot be used as an attribute name. A value of N means that it is not reserved.
RES_SEMI    VARCHAR2(1)     A value of Y means that the keyword is not allowed as an identifier in certain situations, such as in DML. A value of N means that it is not reserved.
DUPLICATE   VARCHAR2(1)     A value of Y means that the keyword is a duplicate of another keyword. A value of N means that it is not a duplicate.
```

According to this information, 'VERSION' is a keyword, but you can use it as an identifier.